# How to handle null values in SSIS script component

Tags: c#, ssis

I have used the following C# code to convert string value name column to Camel case.
It works fine as long as no null values in the input column. When there is a null value, the script component task fails.
Can you please modify this script so that it can handle null values.

```
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

    

    string PARTICIPANTNAME = Row.PARTICIPANTNAME;
    PARTICIPANTNAME = PARTICIPANTNAME.ToLower();
    Row.PARTICIPANTNAME = textInfo.ToTitleCase(PARTICIPANTNAME);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What should it do when the participant name is null, just put a null back on the output buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click into a Script Component, behind the scenes it puts together some scaffolding to deal with primitive types needing to be null. One of the things it does, is add an `_IsNull` property to the column. In your case, I would test to see if the column is null and if it's not `!` then I will perform the operations. No need to do anything if the column is null otherwise you'd just be assigning NULL back to the buffer

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

    // Check to see if the column is null
    if (!Row.PARTICIPANTNAME_IsNull)
    {
        string PARTICIPANTNAME = Row.PARTICIPANTNAME;
        PARTICIPANTNAME = PARTICIPANTNAME.ToLower();
        Row.PARTICIPANTNAME = textInfo.ToTitleCase(PARTICIPANTNAME);
    }
}
```